# span css is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I want to display span tag after input tag. 
[image: I want to display the tick mark after the input text]

But it displays before input tag.
Here I attached css and html code.

### http://jsfiddle.net/sarurakz/8j3r13ec/

**CSS:**

```
 span{
   float:right;
   margin-right:1%;
 }
input {
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   margin-right:20%;
}
```

**Html**:

```
<p>Password<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
<p>Confirm Password<input type="password" name="cpass" id="cpass" size=18 maxlength=50 required><span id='message'></span></p>

validation:
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script>
   $('#pass, #cpass').on('keyup', function () {
   if ($('#pass').val() == $('#cpass').val()) {
    $('#message').html('<img src="image/tick.png" width=15px height=15/>').css('color', 'green');  
     $("#phone").prop('disabled', false); 
     } 
      else{ $('#message').html('<img src="image/delete1.png" width=15px height=15/>').css('color', 'red'); 
      $("#phone").prop('disabled', true);}
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: change the order first span and then input it is because of float:right

Comment: Nice design by the way.

Comment: Pls add a fiddle link whenever possible.It becomes easier to answer

Comment: add span tag after closing the p tag not inside the p tag.

Comment: Why are you floating these elements to begin with? Unnecessary use of absolute positioning.

Comment: @Zword No need for a Fiddle, Stack Overflow has its own version. **Edit: There you go, take a look at Tushar's answer.**

Comment: Ok I didnt know that .Is it new feature added by SO?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, OP needs validation and needs to add the image if the validation is passed. Please checkout my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not having any image so i just placed a random text there in span

```css
span{
   float:right;
  margin-right: 8%;
margin-left: -17%;
 }
input {
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   margin-right:20%;}
```

```html
<p>Password<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
<p>Confirm Password<span id='message'>asdasd</span><input type="password" name="cpass" id="cpass" size=18 maxlength=50 required></p>
```

Comment: Alignment issues will come when you open in wide screen.

Comment: when you run this code there is a full page button click n see if it distorts? :)

Comment: when using float, there is no need for display..! here display will be made to block forcibly by float.

Comment: when using float, there is no need for **display**..! Here `display` will be made to `block` forcibly by float.

Answer (score 3):

I wish a fiddle was there for this, but as per my understanding you can try to add `float: left` to both `input` and `span`

Answer (score 1):

You cant do the validation and adding the tick image just with HTML and CSS. You will need to do the validation in Javascript.

See this **working code snippet:**

```js
document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  var passwordLength = document.getElementById('pass').value.length;
  
  if(passwordLength > 8 && passwordLength < 50){ 
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = 'http://yoozy.com/images/tick-icon.jpg';
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(image, document.getElementById('pass'));
  }  
  
});
```

```css
span{
  float:right;
  margin-right:1%;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right:20%;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter atleast 8 characters in this first password field and focusout to see thie validation working.</p>

<p>
  Password
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required>
</p>
<p>
  Confirm  Password
  <input type="password" name="cpass" id="cpass" size=18 maxlength=50 required>
  <span id='message'></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

use label and padding right and align the span position absolute

using label automatically focuses the input on click of text

```css
label {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
input {
  float: right;
}
span.icon {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 23px;
  background: rgb(18, 208, 27);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>username
  <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required />
</label>

<label>Password
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required /> <span class="icon">&#10003;</span>
</label>
```